# SQL Joins with different granularity

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to join 2 tables of different granularities like so:

**Table MAIN**

```
Id  Name    Col_A   Col_B
1   Name1   L       M
2   Name2   B       K
3   Name3   G       S
```

**Table Detail** *Granularity is determined by ID + Number*

```
Id  Number  Col_C   Col_D
1   1       50      Something1
1   2       23      Something2
1   3       25      Something3
2   1       78      Something4
3   1       100     Something5
3   2       65      Something6
```

This is what I want the final output to look like:

```
Id  Name    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C_Line1 Col_D_Line1 Col_C_Line2 Col_D_Line2 etc…
1   Name1   L   M   50      Something1  23          Something2       …
2   Name2   B   K   78      Something4          
3   Name3   G   S   100     Something5  65          Something6
```

How can I transform Table Detail & join it to Table Main to get the final result?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using mysql, You can use the conditional aggregation :

```
select m.Id, Name, Col_A, Col_B,
          max(case when Number = 1 then Col_C end) as 'Col_C_line1',
          max(case when Number = 1 then Col_D end) as 'Col_D_line1',
          max(case when Number = 2 then Col_C end) as 'Col_C_line2',
          max(case when Number = 2 then Col_D end) as 'Col_D_line2',
          max(case when Number = 3 then Col_C end) as 'Col_C_line3',
          max(case when Number = 3 then Col_D end) as 'Col_D_line3'
from MAIN m
inner join Detail d on d.Id = m.Id
group by m.Id, Name, Col_A, Col_B
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IPy49ZIH)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like

```
select m.*,
       d1.col_c as col_c_line_1 ,
       d1.col_d as col_d_line_1 ,
       d2.col_c as col_c_line_2 ,
       d2.col_d as col_d_line_2 ,
       d3.col_c as col_c_line_3 ,
       d3.col_d as col_d_line_3
from      main   m
left join detail d1 on d1.id = m.id and d1.number = 1
left join detail d2 on d2.id = m.id and d2.number = 2
left join detail d3 on d3.id = m.id and d3.number = 3
```

Assuming you have sensible indices, should be efficient, with a index scan against `main` and a direct index lookup on each of the detail tables, and no aggregation.